# Не добавляется цена для элемента

Tags: битрикс

**Доброго времени суток**
Пытаюсь добавить цену уже существующим товарам, но цены не добавляются.

Причем заметил, если потом в админке руками проставить цену, потом уже метод  CPrice::Add, либо Update, уже цена устанавливается(меняется).

Так же еще заметил, если в $arFields, укажу в "QUANTITY_FROM" => 1, "QUANTITY_TO" => 10, то цена устанавливается методом Add.

1) В общем изначально товар устаналивается без цены, и в поле "Базовая цена" пусто. И тогда если при установки методом CPrice::Add, не чего не устанавливается, даже ошибку не дает, а наоборот, секция if отрабатывает, не цена не устанавливается.

2) Если в $arFields, указать "QUANTITY_FROM" => 1, "QUANTITY_TO" => 10. То цена устанавливается.

3) Если товару руками указать цену в админке, то в последующем можно устанавливать либо обновлять цену.

А как установить цену не  устаналвивая в "QUANTITY_FROM" => 1, "QUANTITY_TO" => 10. И проставляя руками, а сразу не смотря пусто там или нет, просто установить цену которая указана в arFields['PRICE']?
Может кто сталкивался уже с такой задачей? Поделитесь опытом. =)

Вот код:

```
$PRODUCT_ID = 15;
$PRICE_TYPE_ID = 2;

$arFields = Array(
    "PRODUCT_ID" => $PRODUCT_ID,
    "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => $PRICE_TYPE_ID,
    "PRICE" => 29.95,
    "CURRENCY" => "USD",
    "QUANTITY_FROM" => 1,
    "QUANTITY_TO" => 10
);

$res = CPrice::GetList(
        array(),
        array(
                "PRODUCT_ID" => $PRODUCT_ID,
                "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => $PRICE_TYPE_ID
            )
    );

if ($arr = $res->Fetch())
{
    CPrice::Update($arr["ID"], $arFields);
    dump(arFields);

}
else
{
    CPrice::Add($arFields);
    dump(arFields);
}
```

arFields распечатывается, но цена не добавляется и не обновляется.

Comment: Приведите код, который добавляет у вас элементы

Comment: @Taarim, топик поправил.

Comment: а код добавления элемента? Что у вас в productId ?

Comment: @Taarim, в productId  у меня id элемента для которого нужно добавить цену.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю что после добавления элемента вы не делаете CCatalogProduct::Add, чем не создаете элемент каталога для которого уже можно назначить цены. А обновление через админку срабатывает потому что система сама добавляет элемент в таблицу при манипуляциях в админке.

последовательность действий при добавлении товара должна быть такая:

```
$element = new \CIBlockElement()

$result = $element::Add($arFields);

if (is_numeric($result)) {

    CCatalogProduct::Add($arFields); // сюда ID элемента

    CPrice::Update($result, $arFields);
} else {
    echo $element->LAST_ERROR;
}
```

Более подробно можно посмотреть в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/ccatalogproduct/add.php)